# How can I move my events in my iPod calendar to Google? It won't let me move items from iPod to Google but will move Google to iPod

Tags: ipod-touch, google-calendar

I've followed Google's recommendations and steps for synchronising my [iPod Touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Touch), newest OS, with my [Google Calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Calendar). Synchronisation works great when Google Calendar events are added or deleted on the marked for synchronising calendar.  They show up on my iPod.

But when I make changes on the native iPod Touch calendar they are not reflected in the Google Calendar marked for syncing.  What gives?  I also have been unable to do an initial synchronisation that would move my iPod calendar events to my Google Calendar.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take your original calendars online you'll need to export them and import into Google Calendar.

I'm not sure about your setup, if you're using iCal for example you do File / Export...

In Google Calendar select **Settings** / **Calendars** / **Import calendar**.